# Error running a C++ code in Eclipse.It says 'Your program cannot output..'

Tags: c++, eclipse

This error is coming a lot of times. Everytime I run the code it says that your program cannot display output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even I had this problem a few days ago. You have to just press the red terminate button after you run the program.
This may be because your program might be still running on the OS.